# Libgdx animation for HTML5

Tags: libgdx, html5, texture-atlas

I'm working on my first html5 game with libgdx, it's a platform android game that I made a while back that I now want to host on my website. Everything has been going okay till I got to animating the character. The desktop and android versions of the game run just fine but with the html version the game doesn't run and I get the following error:

> GwtApplication: exception: Couldn't find type for class 'com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$AtlasRegion'

When I comment out the code sections for the animation the game runs fine (with the character not animated). What's causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably reflection related, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719343/couldnt-find-type-for-class-com-badlogic-gdx-maps-objects-rectanglemapobject

Comment: I had looked at reflection and I've even used it in my current project for scene2D. Turns out I was using it incorrectly in this case though I was not specifying the full name of the class; I had `<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas"/>` while I need `<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion"/>`. It's now working.